# How to access json in an array?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to access json in a nested array but it is not working yet.

I am developing in laravel an have this

```
public function rave(Request $request){


    $vars = [

       'id' => Request::get('id'),
       'txref' => Request::get('txRef'),
       'flwref' => Request::get('flwRef'),
       'created_at' => Request::get('createdAt'),
       'amount' => Request::get('amount'),
       'status' => Request::get('status'),
       'name' => Request::get('fullName'),
       'email' => Request::get('customer'),

    ];
```

I am able to get and display all in view but `name` and `email` which comes back in the response as

```
"customer":{
    "id":15672,
    "phone":"7667866 ",
    "fullName":"john doe ",
    "customertoken":null,
    "email":"kely@gmail.com",
    "createdAt":"2019-06-09T08:28:56.000Z",
    "updatedAt":"2019-06-09T08:28:56.000Z",
    "deletedAt":null,
    "AccountId":33519
},
```

How do I access the data under `customer` because this

```
'name' => Request::get('fullName'),
'email' => Request::get('customer'),
```

doesn't seem to work like the others

Comment: try json_decode()..

Comment: First use json_decode and then customer['name'], customer['email']? This doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `Request $request` as function parameter,

and check output of

```
echo $request->input('customer.fullName');
echo $request->input('customer.email');
```

Comment: Thanks ````'email' => Request::input('customer.email'),```` worked for me.